# How to allow users to embed an iframe directly in your WordPress theme's pages?

Tags: php, iframe, wordpress-theming

I intend to have a menu on customize WordPress menu to allow users to add iframes on the theme's pages.

I already have written a function to utilize the WP_Customize_Manager class and add several menus to allow users to dynamically add content on the theme's pages. I got stuck trying to allow users to add iframes though.

I'm using a custom class that extends WP_Customize_Control to create a textarea where the users can write HTML on it.

```
 class Customize_HTML_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
        public $type = 'html';
    
        public function render_content() {
            ?>
            <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
            <div class="customize-control-content"><?php echo $this->description; ?></div>
            <textarea rows="10" style="width: 100%;" <?php $this->link(); ?>><?php echo esc_textarea( $this->value() ); ?></textarea>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

to display my theme_mod:

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post( get_theme_mod( 'custom_html_code', '' ) ); ?>
```

and my settings control successfully create a textarea where simple HTMLs works:

```
/**
     ** Donate Section
     */
    $wp_customize->add_section('donate-section', array(
        'title' => 'Donate Section',
        'priority' => 10, 
        'panel' => 'murphy_charity_theme_options'
    ));

    // Custom HTML
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_html_code', array(
        'default'           => '',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post',
    ) );
    
    $wp_customize->add_control( new Customize_HTML_Control( $wp_customize, 'custom_html_code_control', array(
        'label'    => __( 'HTML Code', 'murphy-charity' ),
        'section'  => 'donate-section',
        'settings' => 'custom_html_code',
        'description' => __( 'Enter your HTML code here.', 'murphy-charity' ),
    ) ) );
```

For example, if I add a simple tag like <h1  Title < /h1 > it displays the text Title as a h1. Although, when adding an iframe, it does not emblem it correctly.

For exemple, I wanna add the follows iframe:

```
<script src="https://donorbox.org/widget.js" paypalExpress="true"></script><iframe src="https://donorbox.org/embed/spread-the-compassion-give-to-support-our-organization-s-humanitarian-activities-today" name="donorbox" allowpaymentrequest="allowpaymentrequest" seamless="seamless" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="900px" width="100%" style="max-width: 00px; min-width: 250px; max-height:none!important"></iframe>
```

It does not display the iframe nor save the code of it in my HTML textarea.

My questions are:

Is this the best approach to allow users to insert custom HTML/iframes?

If so, what am I missing in my code that is now showing the inframe but shows simple HTML code?

I appreciate any help on this code.

Comment: `'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post',` - `wp_kses_post` filters out a lot of HTML, that's its purpose. It internally calls `wp_kses`, which can get an array of allowed HTML elements and attributes passed, that it will keep - so perhaps you can specify that as callback, maybe with the help of an anonymous function.

Comment: Bingo! That's the reason, I have overlooked it. Thank you for pointing it up, very well done! I appreciate it. Cheers!